# ms word master document deletes subdocument

Tags: ms-word

I have trouble with `MS Word 2013` `master document`. I created a master document and added subdocuments into it. It was working normally. I saved the document and closed. When i reopened the master document, I could not see first 3 chapters. Rest of chapters were there.

What is the problem with that?

My machine runs on `Win7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my questions answer:

> IMPORTANT: The total size of a master document and its subdocuments cannot exceed 32 megabytes (MB). In Microsoft Windows, the maximum number of subdocuments that are allowed in a master document depends on the number of files that you have open, the size of the files that you have open, the number of programs that you are running, the amount of computer memory, the operating system that you are using, and other system configurations. If you reach this limit when you save the master document, Word cannot save your documents.

So, my files total size exceeds 32 mb and word deletes it randomly.